# Solving for k distinct variables in an equation involving a summation fom 1 to k?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

In a paper I'm reading, there is a value $c = H_{\kappa}(m)$ where $H$ is a hash function whose output is $\kappa$ bits and treated as a positive integer. $m$ is the input to the hash function, which is unimportant. $s$ is a known constant, and $k=\lceil \kappa/\log_{2}(s) \rceil$ (I apologize for the use of both $k$ and $\kappa$ here, I'm just staying consistent with the paper's use).

The part that confuses me is as follows. After calculating $c$, it is said that there are unique $c_{i} \in \{0,\:1,\:...,\:s\}$ (again, I apologize for similar names for distinct variables) such that $c=c_{1}+c_{2}(s+1)+c_{3}(s+1)^{2}+...+c_{k}(s+1)^{k-1}$. This gives me the following:

$$c=\sum^{k}_{i=1}{c_{i}(s+1)^{i-1}}$$

There are two problems I have with this, on which I would appreciate more insight:

1. It is possible that $k>s$, making each $c_{i} \in \{0,\:1,\:...,\:s\}$ unique impossible. This confuses me, as $s$ is usually considerably smaller than $\kappa$ and thus $k>s$ is not only possible but probable.
2. Assuming the above is not an issue, I do not know how to solve for each $c_{i}$ given $c$ without testing each possible combination, which is tedious by hand and undesirably inefficient when automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a formula to express $c$ (presumably in base $10$) in base $(s+1)$, i.e. 
$$c\text{(base 10)}=c_k c_{k-1}...c_3 c_2 c_1\;\;\text{(base $(s+1)$)} $$

To address your issues:

1. Unique in this context would mean that each combination of $c_i$'s is unique for a given $c$, but some of the $c_i$'s may be the same, i.e. not unique amongst each other.
2. To solve for $c_i$'s for a given $c$, divide $c$ and its successive quotients repeatedly by $(s+1)$. The remainders of each stage (from first division to last) are the $c_i$'s for $i=1, 2, \cdots, k$. For example, if $c=17, (s+1)=3$, then by successive division we have 
   $$17\div 3=5 \;\text{r}\; 2\\
   5\div 3=1\;\text{r}\; 2$$
   giving $17_{10}=122_3$, i.e. $c_1=2, c_2=2, c_3=1$

Answer (score 0):

The $c_i$ are the digits of $c$ in base $s +1$. For example, if $s = 9$, this just corresponds to the normal base-10 digits. So if (still with $s=9$) we have, say, $c = 136$, then $c_3 = 1$, $c_2 = 3$ and $c_1 = 6$, simply because $136 = 1\cdot 100 + 3\cdot 10 + 6\cdot 1$.